# Is there a penalty for quitting a Versus A.I. game where all of your teammates are A.I. controlled?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In the [Heroes of the Storm Versus A.I. game mode](http://heroesofthestorm.wikia.com/wiki/Versus_AI_Mode) I can create a game with nothing but A.I. teammates, meaning that there are no other human characters in the game. Once I start a Versus A.I. game with only A.I. opponents and teammates can I quit that game without negatively affecting my MMR, win/loss record or any other stat?

I understand why a Versus A.I. game with human teammates would affect my stats, but can see it going either way with A.I. teammates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that dropping a vs. AI game **will** be permanently recorded, and will count as a loss in your records.

I dropped an AI game simply because I didn't have the time to finish and was dissapointed to see that my loss (which wasn't really a loss, I was winning) was logged in my records. And it will sit there, forever taunting me.

Comment: Does leaving impose a leaver penalty like the one mentioned in [What are the penalties for leaving a game early? QM or HL](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250718/what-are-the-penalties-for-leaving-a-game-early-qm-or-hl/250725#250725)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, it doesn't. should be added to the answer