# What are the penalties for leaving a game early? QM or HL

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Did Blizzard implement any penalties to leavers for QM or HL in Heroes of the Storm?  If so, what are they?

I know this was a popular subject at the end of 2014 but since then I haven't heard about it.
I really dislike when people leave because it ruins the game for the other 9 players but now that I have a baby I understand and now I am the occasional quitter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the game places you into a deserter queue.
The deserter queue means you must play with other players who have similarly left the game early and is not available for Hero League.

Since I left 1 game early it looks like I am only required 1 deserter game.  I will update this if I find more information.

Comment: How can you tell if you're in the deserter queue?

Comment: My answer might be out of date but you could tell in the past by attempting to join Hero League and there was an icon on the top of your screen home menu showing deserter status.

Answer (score 1):

In Hero League, you lose 300 points, dropping you 1 full rank from where you were. In addition to this penalty, you are required to play a quick match before you are allowed to play Hero League again.

Answer (score -1):

You will get penalty, and you will need to play minimum one game along with gamers who also left.
However if you left because of some program error (you have been dropped out) you might not get penalty.

Comment: Have a source for program errors not giving a penalty?