# Penalty for leaving Hero League draft

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

What is a penalty for leaving a Hero League draft? Sometimes it happened to me that while one team had really poor hero draft, one player left and the game never started (no loading screen) and I got message among the lines of "A player you've been matched with has left the game".

What penalty is there for it? I'm especially interested since the changes in ranked system (the bronze, silver, gold, etc.)

Comment: [Duplicate of this?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250718/what-are-the-penalties-for-leaving-a-game-early-qm-or-hl)

Comment: Not really, the linked question deals with leaving during the game. I'm asking about leaving during the draft. Also the linked question describes situation before the change in ranked system.

Comment: Not a full answer since I haven't played in a couple months, but it used to be the same penalty as leaving a game.  -300 HL points and X games in QM before you could do HL.  Not sure how -300 points translates to the new ranked system, I haven't had a chance to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HOTS wiki](http://heroesofthestorm.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_League#Abandoning) says:

> Any player who leaves a Hero League game during Draft Mode will lose a substantial amount of ranked points, become unable to play ranked games until completing a Quick Match game, and will also cause any players in his or her party to incur these penalties.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen streamers receive penalties of 600 rank points. I'm not sure if that is a fixed amount or depends on rank/number of offenses etc.